# Stopping cloud_sql_proxy

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How do I stop a `cloud_sql_proxy` connection?

When I try to connect to my local mysql db I get: `MySQL said: Access denied for user 'root'@'cloudsqlproxy~xx.xxx.xx.xxx' (using password: NO)` even though I'm connecting to `127.0.0.1`, clear the proxy is getting in the way.

I can't find this in the docs... Help!

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked for me on MacOS:

1. Find process 
   `ps | grep cloud_sql_proxy`
2. Kill process based on its id
   `kill 97911`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in windows powershell:

```
Stop-Process -Name "cloud_sql_proxy" -Force
```